# Handle WM_NOTIFY of a grand child control

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I've a MFC dialog and an ActiveX grid control on it. Whenever user tries to edit a date type grid cell, I'm creating a CDateTimeCtrl and showing inside the grid. This control is being created as a child to the grid control, but is a variable in the dialog class.

Now, I'd like to handle the DTN_DATETIMECHANGE message of this date control in my dialog's class. I can see in Spy++, that these messages being sent to the grid control, but how do we handle this in the grand parent's (dialog) class?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating it as a sibling, but just higher in the Z order? You might need to add WS_CLIPSIBLINGS to the parent dialog's style to avoid issues where the grid paints over the date control.

An alternate techique is to use an intermediate child that acts as forwarder, so grid contains forwarder which contains date control. That way your code still receives the notifications; and you still get the appropriate HWND containment effects. (The forwarder typically has no border, and just resizes its only child to take up its entire client area, so is not visible to an end-user.)